# Ajax Request to laravel for uploading a form sometimes work well but some times keep loading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have done following code. Similar code at another place is working fine. But this place sometimes it works fine but some time it keeps loading. I checked my ajax request in network but nothing found. It keeps loading. There is no any JS / PHP Error in console.
I even tried to add cache:fale and async:false/true. But nothing works. 
Note: when i trie to upload a image it keeps loading and if i press upload button again it works and image upload sometimes, some times it wont work.

Please HELP. Thanks in Advance :)

```
$.ajax({
url: 'upload_file',
data: data,
datatype: "json",
type: 'post',
contentType: false,
processData: false,
async: true,
error: function(error) {
     console.log(error);

},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

});

Comment: Do you have a PHP router, and does that router have `upload-file` as a route? Otherwise, the URL is incomplete and should contain the file MIME type (presumably `.php`).

Comment: Hi Randy, I am using laravel, In its route file i have created route upload_file. It works fine some time upload image. but sometimes it not and keep loading...

Comment: Have you took a look at the Network tab in the DevTools?

Comment: I recommend changing the route to `/upload_file`. I think you'll have more consistent results. It is possible that Apache (.htaccess) is getting in the way without the leading slash.

Comment: I remember one time getting my head stuck, because i was uploading the same file consecutively, and i discovered that the second time the browser try to upload the same file, it uploads it parcially. I had to spend a whole day to figure this!

Comment: Hi @Teemu,  I have checked in netwrok tab, its keep loading. Not found any error.

Comment: Hi @marco any idea how can i resolve it

Comment: Randy, I tried /upload_file but it still not work

Comment: There's a size limit of ~2MB for the file to upload, and the server has its own limit. Is a failing file as big?

Comment: no, @Teemu its 80kb,58kb file. Also increased memory limit and execuition time to 1 min

Comment: Well, at least you've done some research. I'd mention those facts in the question, though.

Comment: `contentType: false` jumps from the code, should be not set, as the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` which is usually needed to upload files. Setting it to `false` omits the ContentType from the header of the request.

Comment: My point was that if you keep testing it, change the uploaded file because if you upload it twice in a row, browser will send it partialy.